# MySql Workbench cannot open SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, ssh, mysql-workbench

I have been using MySql Workbench successfully last week, but this morning, it systematically fails to open a SSH tunnel.

I have checked the logs and found the following:

```
16:46:47 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening new one
16:46:54 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to 192.168.200.254
16:46:55 [ERR][sshtunnel.py:notify_exception_error:235]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/mysql-workbench/sshtunnel.py", line 303, in _connect_ssh
    look_for_keys=has_key, allow_agent=has_key, timeout=SSH_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 325, in connect
    t.start_client()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 492, in start_client
    raise e
ValueError: CTR mode needs counter parameter, not IV

16:46:55 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: TunnelManager.wait_connection authentication error: Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager, please refer to logs for details
16:46:55 [ERR][     SSH tunnel]: Authentication error opening SSH tunnel: Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager, please refer to logs for details
16:47:00 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening new one
```

Yet, when I try to connect from a terminal, the SSH connection works fine. Any idea how to solve this issue?

**Findings:**

It seems like there might be a bug with version 6.3.9. I re-installed MySql Workbench with the following (I am on Ubuntu):

```
# The following will remove mysql too
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*

sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get update

# Then reboot your PC

# Re-install MySql Workbench from the Ubuntu software application
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday. My solution was remove Workbench and its dependencies and install it again. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and Workbench 6.3.6.

Comment: That's exactly what I just did. I was on 6.3.9 when the issue happened. Now, after the re-installation, I am on 6.3.6 and it works fine.